# Can I store a function rather than its result to a dictionary value so that it is dynamically updated when the value is called?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'x':val1,'x2':val2}
```

I would like to do something like

```
mydict['x3'] = some_func(mydict['x1'])
```

Where if I later change `mydict['x1']` and call `mydict['x3']`, I return the output of `some_func()` with the new value of `x1`.

I realize this is something class property decorators handle well. I'd like to also be able to change the function stored at the `'x3'` key for that specific object. This is something class properties cannot do to my knowledge (having the underlying function definition changed on an instance of the class).

Comment: Please do not add solutions to the question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `'x3'` to a function in your dict.  Then whenever you want to use it, you can call it.  Something like this:

```
mydict = {'x1': val1,'x2': val2, 'x3': lambda: some_func(mydict['x1'])}
```

Now, `mydict['x3']` is a function.

```
x3 = mydict['x3']()
print(x3)
```

[Here's a quick demo](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwFET3/xR/9xPQhWYX2l6kSElNQgUTJcYSEc@epgilsxpmeG/e4mvyImdtLC6TMw@7@p691cglYEkwcQ0eLdU33Mt84KUmALfpoY94xZ1SQ5LK01BFqT17SxVSEiRH5Z5ayT/1Sd6/WMcPgCSK5TcK6hiHOQw@siR4zh8)

Comment: Ah, so using this I actually devised a solution using properties that works on an instance of the class! Basically you can define an instance method when creating the class, i.e. def set_property(self, name, func): setattr(ClassNameHere, name, property(fget=func)). You can then pass a string to name and a function in the form lambda self: some_func(self.x) to get a property defined by the function some_func(self.x)! Sweet! Even allows new instances to use the same property, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you should define a class rather than using a `dict` directly.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2

    @property
    def x3(self):
        return some_func(self.x1)

mydict = {'x':val1,'x2':val2}
m = MyClass(mydict['x'], mydict['x2'])
assert m.x3 == some_func(m.x1)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using an assert statement. I figured out a variation that works okay using Rocket Hazmat's suggestion. Basially the idea is to define an instance method def set_propery(self, name, func): setattr(ClassName, name, property(fget=func)). You can then call it like instance.set_property(name='x3', func=lambda self: some_func(self))

Comment: The `assert` is just a way of demonstrating (or at least implying) that `m.x3` returns the correct value. It's not really part of the solution itself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on primarily on Rocket's answer, I came up with this test solution.

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def set_prop(self, name, func):
    setattr(Test, name, property(fget=func))

test = Test(1,2)

### Print list of class attributes in __dict__
for key, val in test.__dict__.items():
  print(f"{key} = {val}")

### Create new property, xy defined by self.x * self.y
test.set_prop(name='xy', func=lambda self: self.x*self.y)

print(f"test.x ({test.x}) * test.y ({test.y}) = {test.xy}")

### Test if it is properly linked to changes in x
test.x = 2

print(f"test.x set to {test.x}")
print(f"test.x ({test.x}) * test.y ({test.y}) = {test.xy}")

### Test changing the underlying property formula
test.set_prop('xy',lambda self: self.x/self.y)
print(f"test.x ({test.x}) / test.y ({test.y}) = {test.xy}")
```